# Cardano node sync suddenly stopped at 97.79 %

Tags: cardano-node

My cardano node was 100% synced and it is running in production environment. But suddenly I am seeing that my cardano node block get backed and sync percent is 97.78%.

Error log:

```
[ip-30-0-:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:9719] [2022-11-03 15:48:30.76 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io" Application Exception: 3.130.47.105:3001 MuxError MuxBearerClosed "<socket: 38> closed when reading data, waiting on next header True"
[ip-30-0-:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Warning:4967] [2022-11-03 15:48:30.76 UTC] IP 3.130.47.105:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendPeer (Just (ApplicationExceptionTrace (MuxError MuxBearerClosed "<socket: 38> closed when reading data, waiting on next header True"))) 20s 20s
[ip-30-0-:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:9716] [2022-11-03 15:48:30.97 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io" Application Exception: 54.250.21.52:3001 MuxError MuxBearerClosed "<socket: 35> closed when reading data, waiting on next header True"
[ip-30-0-:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Warning:4967] [2022-11-03 15:48:30.97 UTC] IP 54.250.21.52:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendPeer (Just (ApplicationExceptionTrace (MuxError MuxBearerClosed "<socket: 35> closed when reading data, waiting on next header True"))) 20s 20s
```

Comment: What you posted is unlikely to be the actual cause of the halt, because its messages that a normal running node also gets. What version of the `node` are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Recently, pre-production environment was re-spun (check "build-announcements" in IOG's Technical Community discord), I would suggest you to delete your `db` folder and use latest configuration from [here](https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html#pre-production-testnet).

Comment: I have downloaded latest cardano node and install it with latest config file. Now it is synced.